# why a subspace is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be $K-$vector space with a norm $\|\cdot\|$, and $F$ a subspace with dimension $n$. Show that $F$ is a closed set .

I am trying to show that any convergent sequence of elements $(x_n)_{n \in N}$ of $F$ converge to an element $x \in F$.

This means I need to show that $||x_n-x|| \rightarrow 0$

I see that like a distance which is attended by the fuction $y \rightarrow ||x-y||$ .

How can I show that $ x \in F$?

I have been reading a solution which I don't really understand the intuition behind it :

let $x$ be in $E$ and let $B=\{ y \in F ||y-x|| \leq ||x||\}$
after showing that its a compact, they tried to show that $inf_{y \in F}(||x-y||)= \lambda $ exists.

by definition of $\lambda$ it is the distance between $x$ and $F$

Comment: I am voting to close, because it is not at all clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking for the intuition behind closed sets, or are you asking how to show that a finite dimensional subspace is closed?

Comment: @K.Power actually I am looking for both

Comment: If it is the latter then you will find such a question has been asked before on this site. I should also point out that you need to show that any *convergent* sequence in $F$ has its limit in $F$.

Comment: @K.Power I've been searching but I dont have any idea about the methode they using

Comment: As these are very distinct questions you should definitely ask these in two separate posts.

Comment: Do you know that all norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent?

Comment: @trii yes I already know this result

Comment: After your revisions I am retracting my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in E$ be the limit of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ where $x_n\in F$ for all $n$. If $x=0$, nothing needs to be shown.
Once you know that $B:=\{\,y\in F\mid \|y-x\|\le \|x\|\,\}$ is compact, the continuous(!) map $B\to\Bbb R$, $y\mapsto \|y-x\|$ attains its minimum at some $y_0\in B\subset F$. As $x_n\to x$ and $\|x\|>0$, almost all $x_n$ are $\in B$. Then from $\|y_0-x\|\le \|x_n-x\|\to 0$, we conclude $\|y_0-x\|=0$ and finally $x=y_0\in F$.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach will be to show that a finite-dimensional normed space (over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ or indeed over any complete normed field) is complete.  Then conclude that it is closed in a larger normed space.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1. Use that all norms on $F$ are equivalent to show that all  bounded subsets of $F$ which are closed in $F$ are compact.
2. Show that your sequence is contained in a bounded subset of $F$ which is closed in $F$.
3. Find a  subsequence which has a limit in $F$. What is the limit?

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on GEdgar's suggestion: We know that $F$ has a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$. Using Bolzano-Weierstrass you can show that we have the existence of some $r>0$ such that for any choice of scalars $c_1,\dots,c_n\in K$ we have 
$$\|\sum_{i=1}^nc_ie_i\|\geq r\sum_{i=1}^n|c_i|.$$
Using this you can show that $F$ is complete. Consider a cauchy sequence $(x_m)\subset F$. We know that each $x_m=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^{(m)}e_i$. Using the inequality above and the cauchyness of $(x_m)$ try and show that each sequence of scalars $(c_i^{(m)})$ is also Cauchy. As $K$ is complete we know that these sequences each have a limit in $K$. Show that $(x_m)$ converges to the element of $F$ defined by these scalar limits.

Answer (score 2):

I think K.Power's answer is the best elementary proof but if you don't know the inequality used in his/her answer, you can argue successfully without it:

Let $F=\text{span}\{e^1,\cdots, e^n\},$ where the $ \langle e^i,e^j\rangle =\delta^{ij};\ 1\le i\le n.$

Now, suppose $F\supset (x_n)\to x\in E$. Then, $x_i=a^i_1e^1+\cdots +a^i_ne^n;\ 1\le i\le n.$

Of course, $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $E$, so since

$\|x_m-x_k\|^2=\|(a^m_1-a^k_1)e^1+\cdots (a^m_n-a^k_n)e^n\|^2=|a^m_1-a^k_1|^2+\cdots +|a^m_n-a^k_n|^2$

(because the $(e^i)$ are orthogonal), each $(a_i^m)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $K$.

Assuming now that $K$ is complete, we have $a^m_i\to a_i\in K;\ 1\le i\le n$.

To finish, consider the vector $x=a_1e^1+\cdots +a_ne^n$.

Clearly, $x\in F$ and now, another application of the triangle inequality shows that

$\|x-x_n\|\to 0$, from which it follows that $x_n\to x\in F$

Comment: Are you sure that you can just use the triangle inequality to show that each $(a_i^m)$ is Cauchy? You need to show that $|a_i^m-a_i^k|\leq C\|x_m-x_k\|$ to use that $(x_m)$ is Cauchy. I think you need something like the inequality I used to show that.

Comment: @K.Power:  I assumed wlog orthogonality of the $e^i$ so I think the claim is ok.Or I guess you could use the max norm to avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: Ahh yes that's a neat argument

Answer (score 0):

You haven't correctly stated what you need to prove -- you need to show that any sequence of elements of $F$ that converges in $E$ in fact has its limit in $F$.

But I think it may be easier to show that the complement of F is open.  Consider an element $x \in E \setminus F$.  It has a distance $\gamma \gt 0$ from $F$, given by $||z||$, where $x = y+z$ with $y \in F$ and $z \perp F$.  Then $B(x, \gamma /2) \subseteq E \setminus F$ so $x$ is in the interior of $E \setminus F$.  We chose $x$ arbitrarily, so this proves $E \setminus F$ is open so that $F$ is closed.

Comment: how can we write x=y+z ? E is not an euclidien space to talk about the orthogonal of a subspace !

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the OP knows that finite dimensional subspaces are complemented? This implies they already know that they are closed.

Comment: @K.Power $F + x$ is finite dimensional so you can work there to come up with $z$.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating? I still don't see how you can talk about  $z\perp F$ and knowing that $d(F,x)>0$ without knowing that $F$ is complemented.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “complemented.”  I don’t recall the term from when I last studied linear algebra roughly three decades ago.  But since $F$ is finite-dimensional, fix a basis for $F$, and for any $x \notin F$ and use the basis created by $F+x$ to create an inner product, and therefore a norm, that’s equivalent to the existing norm.

Comment: But $F$ and $F+x$ are *different* Euclidean subspaces, so it makes no sense to speak of an element of one being perpendicular to the other? You can find a $z\in F+x$ such that $z\perp x$ in $F+x$, with $z=x+y$ with $y\in F$, but this in no way implies that $z\perp F$. There is no inner product with which you can compare elements of $F$ with $z$.